# How to set applicationID using Android.mk

Tags: android, android-source

I have a custom rom based on AOSP and I have intend to make App on a system app that is based on Launcher3.
I would like to change App's packageName(or applicationID) from specified in a manifest.

I can change appliationID when build by gradle.
But I don't know how to set applicationID using Android.mk.

How to set applicationID using Android.mk?

**Update:**

I want to set applicationID using Android.MK like I set to applicationID using build.gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way ( at least that I know of ) to specify applicationId on the makefile.

You can always try to replicate what gradle does, which is changing the package field in AndroidManifest as the last step of the build ( after R class generation is already done with original package name field )

Read more on: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

> One more thing to know: Although you may have a different name for the
>   manifest package and the Gradle applicationId, the build tools copy
>   the application ID into your APK's final manifest file at the end of
>   the build. So if you inspect your AndroidManifest.xml file after a
>   build, don't be surprised that the package attribute has changed. The
>   package attribute is where Google Play Store and the Android platform
>   actually look to identify your app; so once the build has made use of
>   the original value (to namespace the R class and resolve manifest
>   class names), it discards that value and replaces it with the
>   application ID.

Answer (score 0):

Application package name can be change in AndroidManifest.xml and your application classes. 
Android.mk doesn’t contain any package name or ApplicationID. it contains your module name to include in source code and add it to build configs.

ApplicationID should set in gradle filer

Comment: I understand about packageName.Cannot set applicationID using Android.mk?